# Neo4j - Mass edit node properties - i.e. mass edit all keys(n)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to perform some data clean up and I was looking for a means to mass edit all my property keys on a set of nodes. In my case, I want to make all the keys(n) upper case and replace blanks with "_" regardless of the column name.

The following sets does this but assumes you know the specific name of the key.

```
MATCH (c:Category)
UNWIND keys = collKeys
SET c.COMPANY = c.Company   
REMOVE c.Company
return c limit 1000
```

The following builds out a list of current keys and then what I want the labels to be.   I'm just not sure how to adjust the SET correctly.
I'm trying to find a way to perform  something like the following to UPPER CASE all my keys(c)

*//SET c.REPLACE(toUPPER(c.Company)," ", "*")  = REPLACE(toUPPER(c.Company)," ", "*")*

```
MATCH (c:Category)
UNWIND keys(c) as collKeys
WITH DISTINCT collKeys
WITH collKeys, REPLACE(toUPPER(collKeys)," ", "_") as collUPPERKeys
WHERE collKeys <> 'source'
SET c.collUPPERKeys = REPLACE(toUPPER(c.collKeys)," ", "_")    //<-- this is where I'm struggling as c.collUPPERKeys doesn't make sense
REMOVE c.collKeys
return  c
```

I realize best practice would be to do this at import but I don't have access to that code as of yet though I intend to perform this upon data load.

Many thanks in advance

EDIT-Is there an apoc function that might do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need APOC to create dynamic properties: take a look at the following post: https://dzone.com/articles/neo4j-dynamically-add-propertyset-dynamic-property

```
CALL apoc.create.setProperty(c, collUPPERKeys, replace(...))
```

Similarly for removing dynamic properties, you will need APOC as well.

```
CALL apoc.create.removeProperties(c, collKeys)
```

YIELD node

If we put it all together:

```
MATCH (c:Category)
WITH c 
UNWIND keys(c) as collKeys
WITH collKeys,c
WITH collKeys, REPLACE(toUPPER(collKeys)," ", "_") as collUPPERKeys,c
WHERE collKeys <> 'source'
// set dynamic properties
CALL apoc.create.setProperty(c, collUPPERKeys, replace(toUPPER(c.collKeys)," ", "_")) YIELD node as foo
// remove dynamic properties
CALL apoc.create.removeProperties(c, [collKeys]) YIELD node
return c
```

Comment: Thanks Tomaž for both the solution and the link to that site, very helpful.   It looks like its having trouble finding 'c' in the apoc as its not contained within the prior WITH....playing around with it now.

Comment: I have edited my answer, btw... if you are dealing with a large graph it would make sense to use apoc.periodic.iterate

Comment: Thanks, still working on my end. I have a DISTINCT keys(c) that seems to be tripping me up and getting rid of didn't help.   Getting an error `Type mismatch: expected List<String> but was String (line 10, column 38 (offset: 366))
"CALL apoc.create.removeProperties(c, collKeys) YIELD node"` on the second apoc call which makes me believe the property isn't on that node.

Comment: my bad, just have to wrap the string into a list as it is meant to remove many properties at once

Comment: I appreciate the help on this one, it has been a learning curve but its logical now that I'm picking up the syntax a bit better.